# Combine two tables in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

I need to ask something is there any way combine two tables different count of columns like:

```
Select a,b,c, from x

 union 

Select d, e from y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to do something like this

```
Select a,b,c from x

 union all  -- ALL doesn't filter dups and is faster

Select d, e, '' as f from y
```

I used '' but you might want to use NULL or 0, NULL will be compatible will all data types, '' will not be

I also used UNION ALL not UNION since it will perform better because it doesn't have to do a sort operation to get rid of dups

the alias f is not needed here either because the top query determines the name of the columns in the resultset

Comment: It might be better to use NULL instead of the empty string and you may also need to coerce data types into compatible types. The other thing that is sometimes helpful is to add a derived column to the set to help identify where the data came from so `SELECT a,b,c,'X' AS src ...`

Comment: that simple... thanks @SQLManace... And also thx billinkc quite better to know...

Comment: I think you need a stronger warning that using `UNION ALL` may produce different results. As stated it is ambiguous, "[`UNION ALL`] doesn't have to do a sort operation to get rid of dups" could be erroneously interpreted as, "[`UNION ALL`] gets rid of dups without having to do a sort operation".

Answer (score 1):

Note that

```
select a, b, c from x
union
select d, e, '' as f from y;
```

and

```
select d, e, '' as f from y
union
select a, b, c from x;
```

will yield different results i.e. the attribute names from the first-appearing table will be used.

Perhaps better to be unequivocal by explicitly renaming the columns in the second table e.g.

```
select a, b, c from x
union
select d AS a, e AS b, '' as c from y;
```

Comment: ive already fixed the issue without renaming... rename is not neccesary its getting first table columns names thx again...

Answer (score 0):

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
from mytable1
union all
select col5, col6, null as col7, '' as col8
from mytable2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
first table 
id
name
second table 
name 
seatno
```

if you want to join on name & there are some duplicate names in both table the use ROW_NUMBER in join query!

Comment: Please clarify your answer to improve it, it's not very clear what you mean. And can you give an example?